# Один стиль - Две анимации

Tags: html, css

есть один css стиль:

```
.heart{
  color: transparent;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #FF3008,#B91D28,#FF3008);
  background-size: 1000px 100%;
  animation: gradient_animate 25s linear infinite;
  animation: heart_beat 1.6s linear;
  transition: 0.25s;
}
```

и две анимации:

```
@keyframes heart_beat {
  0% {
    font-size: 15px;
  }
  25% {
    font-size: 17px;
  }
  50% {
    font-size: 15px;
  }
  75% {
    font-size: 17px;
  }
  100%{
    font-size: 15px;
  }


 @keyframes gradient_animate {
  0% {
    background-position-x: 0;
  }
  100% {
    background-position-x: 10000px;
  }
}
```

Как сделать, чтобы работали обе анимации, а не только одна?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Перечисляйте анимации через запятую:

```css
animation: gradient_animate 25s linear infinite, heart_beat 1.6s linear;
```

Comment: Вот она ирония судьбы За хороший ответ, который требует глубоких знаний, творческого подхода чаще всего 0 или +1, у тебя а за простенький ответ, требующий 20 секунд и который есть во всех туториалах CSS богатый урожай. Это просто мысли вслух Юра. Причем неоригинальные..

Comment: @Alexandr_TT: вот, не поверишь - эта очевидность обманчива - я в своё время кое-как нашёл инфу как раз по перечислению и сокращённым свойствам. Сейчас помню или просто знаю, что она где-то есть, а на тот момент, голову ломал, а результаты поиска наводили на мысль, что такой инфы вообще не существует. Или написано так, что "не знал и голова не болела"))

Comment: вполне возможно, зачем я это написал, не знаю :) Просто наблюдается тенденция. И вопрос ни к тебе, ни ко мне, надо принимать как данность